# Oracle SQL: If a condition isn't met create a record in the returned results

Tags: sql, oracle

Ok...so what I'm trying to do is to have a query (I can't use PL/SQL as the query is utilized by an application that can't handle PL/SQL) that simply queries a table and if a particular condition isn't met, it actually creates a record with that condition in the returned results (not actually create a record in a table).

To set this up, imagine there is only one table with the following columns: ID, TEST, and SPEC and may have data like the following:

```
1234   LIMIT_TEST    Total of limits
4321   LIMIT_TEST    Total of limits
5678   LIMIT_TEST    Etha
8765   LIMIT_TEST    Metha
```

The SPEC column is produced by a case, when, then statement that pulls expressions out of a SPECIFICATION column.

So you'll see there are actually 3 LIMIT_TESTs:

- Total of Limits
- Etha
- Metha

However, for ID 1234, there is only "Total of limits". What I need to have the query return is something like:

```
1234  LIMIT_TEST  Total of limits
1234  LIMIT_TEST  null              Etha
1234  LIMIT_TEST  null              Metha
```

(Imagine in the case statement a column is added to put what the nulls are for).

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could form a `UNION` between your main query and another which includes a static `NULL` in its `SELECT` clause, and uses a `NOT EXISTS` in its `WHERE` clause to determine the absence of `Etha` and `Metha`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it...

```
select
    c.id, c.test, d.spec, case when d.spec is null then c.spec else null end as missing_spec
from
    (select a.id, a.test, b.spec from TABLE_NAME a, (select distinct spec from TABLE_NAME) b) c,
    TABLE_NAME d
where c.id = d.id (+) and c.test = d.test (+) and c.spec = d.spec (+)
order by c.id, c.spec;
```

Assumption:  There will only ever be one record in the table for each unique combination of id, test, and spec.

1) Cartesian join the source table with a distinct list of the spec values.  This will provide a base result list having a record for each unique combination of all possible ids, tests, and spec values.
2) Left outer join the source table.  This will allow you to identify which of all the possible unique combination are actually present in the source table.
3) Add a case to the select clause for the final results column that displays null when the combination is found and the spec value if missing.

If it is possible for the source table to have multiple records for a single combination of id, test, and spec, then you would want to add `distinct` before the `a.id` in line 4 (as mentioned by Ponder Stibbons).

Comment: Edit the answer with explanation.

Comment: Inventive. But if there are two rows for same id it returns multiplied rows, I suspect that adding `distinct` in line 4, before `a.id` will help (not sure of that).
Please correct query and explain in short words, it's interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, test, decode(spec, ms, spec) spec,  nullif(ms, spec) missing
  from (select id, test, spec, ms, 
        row_number() over (partition by id, ms order by decode(spec, ms, 1)) rn
      from t cross join (select distinct spec ms from t) dt )
  where rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fbf3/3) (I added one row here for `id=1234, spec ='Etha'` to check scenario 
where two specs for one id exists). Table name is `T`, not creative.

---

Explanation:

- select `distinct spec` - obvious step
- cross join distinct specs with our table - probably must be done somehow in any solution (union, exists, etc.)
- enumerate rows depending on if spec's are equal then this rows have priority - this is done by `row_number()`
- take only rows with `rn = 1`, rest is the matter of presentation (functions `decode` and `nullif`).